# Javascript innerhtml Display

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Hi I made a js script for coin tossing and when I press the button to start it nothing appears

```
    <script>
    var coin = Math.random();
    if(coin <= 0.5){
     return "H";
    }
    else{
    return "T";
    }

    var coinFlip = function(){
      document.getElementById("flip").innerHTML = coin;
    }
  </script>
```

This is the button

```
<button onClick="coinFlip()">Flip</button>
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coin is a random number the return is not doing what you think.

```js
var coinFlip = function() {
  var coin,
    chance = Math.random();
  if (chance <= 0.5) {
    coin = "H";
  } else {
    coin = "T";
  }
  document.getElementById("flip").innerHTML = coin;
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", coinFlip);
```

```html
<div id="flip"></div>
<button id="btn">Flip</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it reflip without reloading the page then pressing the button?

Comment: That code should reflip every time you press the button.

Comment: Once it has flipped once it stays to that letter no matter how many times I press it so I have to reset it by refreshing the page.

Comment: I just made the demo work above and it shows H and T to me.... What is different with your code?

Comment: This is what I was using to show it

 <p style="font-size:75px" id="flip"></p>

Comment: The demo works for me but not mine so Ill try and work out whats wrong, thanks.